# Create a payment link given an email

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Say I have a given email that is not mine (a customer) `xx@gmail.com`.

Say I would like to let another unknown customer pay money to this email. (= marketplace)

So in my website anyone who click a button is able to pay using Paypal to this given email. I have no relationship with any of them.

Is it possible with the API ? if so where is the reference to it ?
Is there any generic structure to create a link to request money based on a given email `xx@gmail.com` ?

In *Adaptive Payment*, Paypal says :

```
Adaptive Payments is now a limited release product
```

Which means ?

Comment: I have implemented the Adaptive payment. Check this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296001/paypal-adaptive-payment-in-java-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the Express Checkout APIs, but based on what you're saying I would recommend you just use PayPal Standard.

This URL can be used as a template to build a payment request.  Just replace the email in the `business` parameter with the email you want the payment to go to.  Then anybody can use that URL to send a payment to that person.

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&bn=AngellEYE_PHPClass&business=email@gmail.com&amount=25.00&currency_code=USD
```

So you can see this specifies the email address for where the payment should go, and it also includes the amount and currency code.

You can add any parameters you want from the [PayPal Standard Variables Reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/).

Comment: Thanks! So simple yet could not find it. How would you take a fee in the middle using Express API ? Can you please direct me to an actual example to accept money from A as B (our website), take a fee (at B) and push the rest to C ?

Comment: Well, what I gave you is not Express Checkout.  It's PayPal Standard.  There really isn't a perfect solution for that until Marketplaces becomes available (which may be a while).  Here's an [article I wrote](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-split-payments-express-checkout-billing-agreements-reference-transactions/) about work-around with EC.

Comment: Where is the article? What about Adaptive payment?

Comment: It's on the linked text that says "article I wrote" in my previous comment.  Adaptive Payments is no longer being approved for new apps.

Comment: Oh sorry it was dark didn’t see it’s a link :) thank you.